# Javascript Date.UTC() analog in .NET

Tags: c#, javascript, datetime

How to convert C# DateTime object to have the same output when using javascript Date.UTC() method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Date.UTC returns the number of milliseconds since 1970 for a date in UTC. So the following should work::

```
Convert.ToInt64((DateTime.UtcNow- new DateTime(1970,1,1,0,0,0,DateTimeKind.Utc)).TotalMilliseconds)
```

This is more or less equivalent to what you will get from Date.UTC if you entered today. You can use the DateTime constructor to specify the moment you are interested in, make sure to set the kind to utc though.

Answer (score 1):

[`DateTime.UtcNow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.utcnow.aspx) would give you the same result.

> Gets a DateTime object that is set to the current date and time on
>   this computer, expressed as the Coordinated Universal Time (UTC).

Or if you want to construct your own `DateTime` *(like [Date.Utc() in Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC))* and then get Universal time then you can do:

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(2013, 11, 05, 0, 0, 0);
DateTime utcDt =  dt.ToUniversalTime();
```